# Center Controls in Android View..HowTo?

Tags: android

i have a Fragment with following Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingLeft="5dip" 
    android:paddingRight="5dip"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:id="@+id/dateItemRow"


    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/timeField"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

        android:gravity="center"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:paddingBottom="0dp"
        android:textColor="#5d6265"

        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/rowBackground"
        android:layout_width="3dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:background="#33b5e6"

        >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/seperator"
            android:layout_width="2dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:text="" 
            />

    </LinearLayout>

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/mycheckBox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:button="@drawable/custom_checkbox_design"        
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

How you (hopefully) see this is a Layout where on the Left site is a Time Field then kind a Border to separate the TimeField from the CheckBox. What i'm looking for is to set all of them to Center.
Actual everything is on the Left Site. 
All this is in a ListView what i have described like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#e8e8e8" >
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"        
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:background="#e8e8e8" > 
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

I really have NO Idea how i can get this. THX for your HELP!!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
android:gravity="center"
```

to your outer LinearLayout.

Comment: unfortunately this is not what helps... :-(